How long would a space tether on Phobos need to be to exceed earth's escape velocity?
Many futurists and science-fiction enthusiasts talk about one day building a space tether anchored to Mars' moon Phobos, extending 6,000 kilometres from the moon to Mars' lower atmosphere, and usually a similar distance from the moon into space, to provide spacecraft with a cheap system for landing and takeoff from the planet.
For reasons that are too complicated to get into here, I would like to know how long a Mars-Phobos tether would have to be for the speed at the far end of the tether to exceed Earth's escape velocity, (yes, earth's escape velocity, not Mars'), and reach the arbitrary speed of, say, 25 km/s
I have tried to work this out using online calculators but can't find any that are relevant.

Earth escape speed (ignoring atmospheric drag) is ~11.2 km/s ~= 25,000 MPH. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity

I'm curious what relevance the escape velocity at earth's surface has when not on the surface of the earth? At a position somewhere near Phobos, the particular velocity of 11.2km/s does not represent anything at all conceptually related to escape from any body whatsoever.

Phobos has a very rapid orbital period that is more than 3 times faster than the rate of rotation of Mars. Any tether from Phobos down to the lower Martian atmosphere would  burn up.

A space tether gives the objects on the tether a speed that depends on the orbital speed of the tether base. Phobos orbits Mars at a speed of 2.138 km/s, on average.
If you want to move at 25 km/s, your radius to Mars' center has to be 25/2.138 of Phobos' distance to Mars' center. The speed is proportional to the radius.

You've already accepted Hobbes' answer, which is correct as far as I know, and its brevity is admirable.  I'm going to belabor some points to touch on some things that were brought up in comments and another answer.
First:
the basic operating principle at work here is that Phobos has some average orbital period about Mars, $\omega$.  Its average speed about Mars is $\omega * r$, where $r$ is the distance from Phobos' center of mass to roughly Mars' center of mass.
Points on a rigid tether extending from Phobos toward Mars move more slowly around Mars, varying linearly with the distance $r_\text{point}$ from Mars' center to wherever you're asking about.  The speed becomes $\omega * r_\text{point}$.  Because $r_\text{point}$ is closer to Mars, the speed is lesser than Phobos' velocity.
Points on a rigid tether extending from Phobos away from Mars move more quickly around Mars, again varying linearly with the distance $r_\text{point}$ from Mars' center to wherever you're asking about.  The speed becomes $\omega * r_\text{point}$.  Because $r_\text{point}$ is further away from Mars, the speed is greater than Phobos' speed.
As Hobbes pointed out, we can work out (assuming Phobos is in a circular orbit for the time being, which it almost is--we'll use the Wikipedia article for all our numbers) that, for a goal speed of 25 km/s, starting at Phobos' speed of 2.138 km/s and orbital radius of 9376 km, we find a release radius as follows:
$$9376 \text{ km} * {25.00 \text{ km/s}\over{2.138 \text{ km/s}}} = 109,600\text{ km}$$
(rounded to 4 significant figures) which means the tether is more than 100,000km long, assuming it's a rigid structure extending above Phobos.  The actual engineering of such a long structure might not be possible.  If it isn't rigid, things get more complicated than I will allow in this answer.
Addressing some of the issues expressed:

Phobos has a very rapid orbital period that is more than 3 times faster than the rate of rotation of Mars. Any tether from Phobos down to the lower Martian atmosphere would burn up. – Slarty
This is true.  The traditional sci-fi answers would be using railguns to move Phobos to a stationary orbit so that the tether would match Martian ground-speed (I think this is done in KSR's Red Mars, but I might be misremembering which moon) or a Skyhook.  The Skyhook concept adds additional rotation to the system, but the math is pretty similar. You'd want the lower end, constrained by Phobos' altitude and Mars' radius to around 6000km (less, actually, but only a little), to be going close to the speed of Mars' surface; this is complicated by Phobos' orbit not being quite equatorial, but for simplicity we'll assume it is:
$$v_\text{equator} = 0.241\text{ km/s} \approx 2.138\text {km/s} * \omega_\text{skyhook} * 6000 \text{km}$$
$$\omega_\text{skyhook} \approx {0.241\text{ km/s}\over{2.138\text {km/s} * 6000 \text{km}}} = 2*10^{-5}\text{ radians/s} $$
That's pretty low, so the rotation of the skyhook doesn't give us a lot of extra velocity at the top end (2 cm/s per kilometer of tether).  So you end up needing a skyhook from Phobos to vary its length dramatically to reach the goal speed of 25 km/s without also extending all the way through Mars.

Incorrect. That's not how orbit works. Going closer means a faster orbit.
Objects on a tether as-proposed aren't moving at orbital speed for their position.  In fact, only the center-of-mass of a spacecraft ever is, and all the parts of a spacecraft pull on each other in various ways because they're not exactly in the spot that they would be orbiting at if they all came apart.
For a tether that remains oriented radially / vertically with respect to Mars, the parts below the orbital center-of-mass (which should generally be near Phobos because of its mass, see below) are moving too slow to orbit and try to fall, but the rest of the system holds it up.  Parts above the orbital center-of-mass are moving too fast and try to rise, but the rest of the system holds it down; eventually, they move so-too-fast that they're at escape velocity (or even faster), as the question poses.  The rest of the system holds it in this not-orbit until the mass is released, at which point it is free to proceed on whatever freefall trajectory its position and velocity give it.

Accelerating something requires energy though, which is conserved.
Work is done in this system by reaction forces between the tether and the object being accelerated.  If you integrated it all out, you'd find that the momentum of the system is conserved and Phobos is slowed down slightly during this process.  An object being lifted from Mars' surface near the equator would create the following relation:
$$m_\text{object} * v_\text{object} + m_\text{Phobos} * v_\text{Phobos} = m_\text{object} * 25_\text{ km/s} + m_\text{Phobos} * v_\text{Phobos,after}$$
$$m_\text{object} * 0.241\text{ km/s} + 1.06*10^{16}\text{ kg}  * 2.138\text{ km/s} = m_\text{object} * 25_\text{ km/s} + 1.06*10^{16}\text{ kg} * v_\text{Phobos,after}$$
$$ v_\text{Phobos,after} = 2.138\text{ km/s} - {m_\text{object} * (25_\text{ km/s} - 0.241\text{ km/s})\over{1.06*10^{16}\text{ kg}}} $$
As you can see, $m_\text{object}$ has to be quite high for $v_\text{Phobos,after}$ to change appreciably, because $m_\text{Phobos}$ is so high.
There's some subtlety here; we assumed earlier that $\omega$ doesn't change from Phobos' initial value.  Really, angular momentum is a conserved quantity but, for exactly the same reasons as in the momentum-balance equation above, Phobos (or eventually the Phobos+structure system) has so much angular momentum (thanks to its mass and angular velocity) that the exchange with any object of engineerable size barely slows it down.  Accounting for it this way would become much more important if you were trying to throw masses comparable to Phobos' (for example, if you were thinking about long-period asteroid mining of Phobos itself).


A lovely figure of the system as I understand it and have laid out above (as a space elevator subset of the space tether) is provided by Weinstein in "Space Colonization Using Space-Elevators from Phobos", reproduced below. The values used for orbital radius and velocity are slightly different than I used above.

